# Docker could not connect to mysql database which also is a container

Tags: docker

I would like to deploy my asp.net core project (connected to mysql datatbase) to docker, after building, I have an image called `myapp:v1`.

Now I want to run a container and connect to my localhost mysql ( in another container).

Below Example is what I have tried:

My IP: 10.1.1.1

MYSQL Port: 3306

Docker command:`docker run -d --name Test.WebApp --restart always -e DBSERVER=10.1.1.1:3306 -p 8082:443 -p 8083:80 myapp:v1`

But it always have errors for connection error to database.What is the problem?

**Update 2021/12/09:**

The mysql database is another container.

My asp.net core connection string:

`"ConnectionStrings:CicadaDB": "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=CicadaDB_20211013;User Id=root;Password=Cicada@123;CharSet=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;SSL Mode=None;IgnoreCommandTransaction=True;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True",`

It works well when I test my project locally without docker.

When I dbbug/run project with visual studio `Docker` on the top,I need to modify the Server to `10.1.1.1` and it also works.

But using command to make it run as container it failed.The error is shown like
`An error occurred during the connection to the database, check whether the server is normal and the connection string is correct,`

```
 Connection open error . Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

at SqlSugar.AdoProvider.GetDataReader(String sql, SugarParameter[] parameters)

at SqlSugar.AdoProvider.SqlQuery[T,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7](String sql, Object parameters)

at SqlSugar.AdoProvider.SqlQuery[T](String sql, SugarParameter[] parameters)

at SqlSugar.AdoProvider.SqlQuery[T](String sql, Object parameters)

at SqlSugar.DbMaintenanceProvider.GetDataBaseList(SqlSugarClient db)

at SqlSugar.MySqlDbMaintenance.CreateDatabase(String databaseName, String databaseDirectory)

at SqlSugar.DbMaintenanceProvider.CreateDatabase(String databaseDirectory)

at Cicada.Platform.WebApp.CicadaServiceExtensions.CicadaInit(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /src/Cicada.Platform.WebApp/CicadaServiceExtensions.cs:line 133

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()

at Cicada.Platform.WebApp.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /src/Cicada.Platform.WebApp/Startup.cs:line 97

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)

at Cicada.Platform.WebApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Cicada.Platform.WebApp/Program.cs:line 10
```

Comment: Had you try to go into to container then do telnet to your DB?

Comment: Where is the database actually running; in another container, outside a container on the same host, on the network somewhere?  (All of these things separately believe they are `localhost`, and they are different from the `localhost` your application container thinks it is.)  How have you configured your application to connect to the database?  What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @David Maze I updated mu question.

Comment: @David Maze When I change the connectionstring to my ip,it works in visual studio debug with Docker.But I want to use above command to run in backstage.Is there any idea?